# Azure FTP task suddenly fails

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have a pipeline that uploads some files to a remote FTP server. The last pipeline runs have been successful and the last one was about 2 weeks ago. Today, the FTP upload task is failing with:

`getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN ftp.site4now.net ftp.site4now.net:21 (control socket)`

I've loaded the FTP site from my local PC successfully. But the Azure pipeline reports this. There are no other errors. Does anyone know how to resolve this?

Edit: I just recalled. We changed from an older version of Ubuntu on the agent build machine in Azure, to a newer version. Prior to that it worked. It seems to maybe be related to that. Our builds showed warnings of agent depreciation.

Comment: Changing the build agent to Windows-2019, resolved the issue. I'll add the answer as soon as I am allowed to. Hopefully helps someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was a change in Build Agent machines. There was a warning about the selected one becoming depreciated. We changed to a later version of Ubuntu, and the errors started.

Switching to Win-2019 solved the issue. I'm not su+ure why.